# Javascript routing in Play 2.5 for Java?

Tags: javascript, java, playframework-2.5

The documentation here [PlayFramework JavascriptRouting](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaJavascriptRouter) says to use play.Routes:

```
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;
import play.Routes;
public Result javascriptRoutes() {
    return ok(
        Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes",
            routes.javascript.Users.list(),
            routes.javascript.Users.get()
        )
    ).as("text/javascript");
}
```

However, the JavaDocs say that Routes is deprecated, and suggests using JavaScriptReverseRouter.create, for which I find the documentation confusing, and I can't find any examples or tutorials anywhere.  Can someone please clarify?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
return ok(
        JavaScriptReverseRouter.create("jsRoutes",
             routes.javascript.Users.list(),
             routes.javascript.Users.get()
        )
).as("text/javascript");
```

Comment: That did it.  I had some other issues, but eventually figured it all out.

Comment: Now also at the docs: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaJavascriptRouter#Router-resource

Comment: @koppor this doesn't turn up when i search play for "javascript router", only the scala version does - is there something that can be done to remedy?

Comment: @bharal I checked the link and it works. It points to Java code and shows how it works. Including the client-side JavaScript-part. - Which links are you referring to? - Maybe we should move to [a chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139/javanot-android) as it seems, it will be a long discussion.

Comment: @koppor no no, the link works. I just mean i cannot "search" and naturally find that link - if you had not referenced the link, I would have been unable to find it because playframework/google search do not return it